# Overleaf and VS Code table incompatibility

Tags: tables, miktex, overleaf, nicematrix, vscode

Hi there I'm fairly new to LaTeX; hence, my code might not be the most efficient and effective but it gets the job done.  So far, I've been working and experimenting in `Overleaft` but I'm setting on the side my local environment (VS Code + MikTeX) to keep a copy of my projects.
Everything seems to be working just fine but I have a table built with `\usepackage{nicematrix}` that gets printed/built in `Overleaf` but not in `VS Code`. In particular, I'm prompted the following message:

> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{verbatim} %comments multiple lines

\usepackage{nicematrix} %forces v-line contiguity
\usepackage{multirow} %allows for multirow tables
\usepackage{booktabs} %allowas for proper v&h spacing in a table
\usepackage{amsmath} %could be used to set table high and width
\usepackage{diagbox} %single cell diagonal line
\usepackage{array} %set specific tables' rules
\usepackage{float} %object to the right place

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl} % Line breaks for urls

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Supplementary Table}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Supplementary Figure}

%%line editing package and function
\usepackage{arydshln}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[inkscapearea=page]{svg} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{ #1 \}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{\textbf{Item's description}. Caption}
\label{table:label}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{NiceTabular}{l|ccc|ccc}
\thickhline
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{graph 1}} \\
\thickhline
\Block[fill=white]{2-1}{\diagbox{GRAPH}{METRIC}} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{tool1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{tool2} \\
\cdashline{2-7}[.4pt/1pt]
& \textit{recall} & \textit{precision} & \textit{F1} & \textit{recall} & \textit{precision} & \textit{F1} \\
\hline
a & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
b & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
c & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\hdashline
d & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
e & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
f & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\
g & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 \\
\hdashline
h & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 \\\hline
\hline
\thickhline
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{graph 2}} \\
\thickhline
\Block[fill=white]{2-1}{\diagbox{GRAPH}{METRIC}} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{tool1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{tool2} \\
\cdashline{2-7}[.4pt/1pt]
& \textit{recall} & \textit{precision} & \textit{F1} & \textit{recall} & \textit{precision} & \textit{F1} \\
\hline
a & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
b & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
c & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\hdashline
d & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
e & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
f & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\
g & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 \\
\hdashline
h & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 \\\hline
\thickhline
\end{NiceTabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Now, I understand the source of the problem but cannot debug it since in `Overleaf`, which I assume is more resilient, the script works just fine. If someone with more experience and a better eye for these issues could help will be great!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think, that the shown code compiles at Overleaf without errors, because `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` are missing, the backslash of the `begin{table}` is missing, several `\Block` do not end (missing `}`) etc. So you first should correct all these errors. Note: Even if Overleaf shows a PDF, which *seems to be correct*, you should always correct all errors, because otherwise you will never be sure, that the PDF *is really correct*.

Comment: Thanks @cabohah, I fixed what you mentioned and tried in `Overleaf` and works as expected. Apologies, I copy pasted without double-checking everything was correct and missed out on those, sorry again. However, the documents are exactly the same in both `Overleaft` and `VS Code` which seems to not explaining why this is happening...

Comment: vscode is just the editor what matters is the version of packages in use. show the nicematrix version number as printed in the logs at overleaf and your local machine, your example gives an error in texlive 2023 but not texlive 2022

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If I'm not wrong this is the `nicematrix` version used by `Overleaf`: Package: nicematrix 2023/06/30 v6.20a Enhanced arrays with the help of PGF/TikZ. I assume I need to have the exact same one in MikTeX?

Comment: more interesting is what version you have locally (as we can see overleaf:-) texlive 2023 updated (and probably miktex) has `Package: nicematrix 2023/11/16 v6.25`  which is newer, so either the package changed something or introduced a bug. The maintainer is usually around and will see your nicematrix tag.....

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. Indeed, I was checking exactly how to revert `nicematrix` to an older install in MiKTex. If possible, I will keep this open till the developer sees whether we can address this. Thanks again!

Comment: A note to your assumption that Overleaf is more resilient: Overleaf is just a nice web-interface for maintaining .tex-input-files. For compiling .tex-input files the TeX platform TeX Live is used. In the Menu you can choose between different TeX Live releases. By default - afaik - TeX Live 2023 is used. Both with TeX Live 2022 and with TeX Live 2023, using the pdflatex-engine, I only get a warning about "Unused \captionsetup[figure]" when compiling your example as is now after you did some edits.

Comment: @UlrichDiez thanks for the note, it happened the same to me in some instances. Please, go on and remove the `\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Supplementary Figure}`; this should solve the problem, as there are not actual figures in this document.

Comment: This is an incompatibility between `nicematrix` and `arydshln` introduced in version 6.25 of `nicematrix`. I will write a new version of `nicematrix` that solves that bug...

Comment: @Matteo It is just a warning, not an error, so I don't take this for a serious problem.;-)

Comment: Wonderful @F.Pantigny, thank you so much for the support and thanks to everyone for the insights. As I said, I'm quite new to LaTeX world in general and couldn't figure out by myself the nature of this issue. Commenting the package and the respective horizontal lines calls make the script executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.26 of 2023-11-22) solves that incompatibility between `nicematrix` and `arydshln` (however, `nicematrix` provides tools to draw dashed rules and, therefore, it is not recommended to use `nicematrix` in conjunction with `arydshln`).

Comment: Much appreciated @F. Pantigny. I saw your update was uploaded yesterday on CTAN. Once available on MikTex I will download it for sure! In the meantime, I also looked at the options provided by `nicematrix` itself. Thanks again!